# Removing a Line Feed substring without using vba

Tags: excel

I am using a Vlookup to take the content of a cell in another sheet. The problem is that this cell has 2 lines, written by VBA, seperated by chr(10) or vbLF (equivalent of alt+enter to switch lines in a cell). I only want the first line. This is what I have right now (RechercheV is Vlookup in French):

```
=RECHERCHEV("btn_" & etape_doc;LangueEtapes!A:D;3;FAUX)
```

It returns "Transfert1Responsable:IC" (in the target cell, Transfert1 is on the first line, and Responsable:IC is on the next). I want to break at the line change and only retain "Transfert1".

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out a line feed is called CHAR(10) in English and CAR(10) in French. So using this: http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel-tips/how-to-use-excels-vlookup-function

I changed my formula to this:

```
= GAUCHE(RECHERCHEV("btn_" & etape_doc;LangueEtapes!A:D;3;FAUX); TROUVE(CAR(10); RECHERCHEV("btn_" & etape_doc;LangueEtapes!A:D;3;FAUX))-1)
```

And it worked perfectly!

Source for Char(10): http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2011/08/08/add-line-break-in-excel-formula/

EDIT: The whole goal of this was to add an IF statement that would change the text based on the language as chosen by the user. The language is chosen from a validation list in another sheet (French of English) and the VlookUp looks at column 3 for French version, and column 4 for English version. After adding the IF statement I ended up with this monster (This is aside the question, I'm posting in case anyone want to go further with their VlookUp functions):

```
=SI(Paramètres!cell_langue="FR"; GAUCHE(RECHERCHEV("btn_" & etape_doc;LangueEtapes!A:D;3;FAUX); TROUVE(CAR(10); RECHERCHEV("btn_" & etape_doc;LangueEtapes!A:D;3;FAUX))-1);  GAUCHE(RECHERCHEV("btn_" & etape_doc;LangueEtapes!A:D;4;FAUX); TROUVE(CAR(10); RECHERCHEV("btn_" & etape_doc;LangueEtapes!A:D;4;FAUX))-1))
```